# Надо ли склонять топоним Барсуки?

Tags: склонение, топонимика

*- Я ездила в детский дом, в Барсуки.*

*- Куда именно в Барсуки?*

Правильно здесь построен диалог, или в вопросе топоним необходимо склонять?

*- Куда именно в Барсуках?*

Или оба варианта верные, и пунктуация соблюдена?

Или это напрямую зависит от первого обращения?

*- Я ходила в детский дом, в Барсуках.*

*- Куда именно, в Барсуках?*

Так же прошу поправить мою пунктуацию.

Есть ещё такое мнение:

> Корректно использование в вопросе и ответе одной и той же падежной формы топонима.

Это получается форма падежа заимствуется из предыдущего предложения. Существуют какие-то суждения на тему унаследованния формы падежей?

Answer (score 2):

Диалог:

— Я ездила в детский дом, **в Барсуки.**  (Ездила  (куда?) в Барсуки, форма В.п., топоним в роли уточняющего обстоятельства обособляется).

— Куда именно **в Барсуках?**  (В Барсуках (где?), форма П.п., обстоятельства неоднородные, отвечают на разные вопросы, поэтому нет обособления).

**Грамматическая справка**

1) Топонимы в форме мн. числа обычно склоняются: Барсуки, в Барсуках.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=73

- Названия, оканчивающиеся на -и, -ы
  Большую тенденцию к склоняемости имеют топонимы на -ы: в Катовицах, Фивах, Татрах, Каннах, Чебоксарах.
  Обычно не склоняются названия на -и: из Чили, Тбилиси, Нагасаки.

2) При наличии родового слова такие названия не склоняются: в Барсуках — в поселке Барсуки.

Comment: Тоесть диалог: "- Я ездила в детский дом, в Барсуки.

- Куда именно в Барсуках?" Нелогичен?

Comment: Сравним:  На каникулы собираемся съездить (куда?) в Москву. Куда в Москве  (где?) можно сходить с детьми?  Также: В какое именно место в Барсуках вы ездили?

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня техническое образование, и на вопрос "логично или нет?", я всецело воспринимаю ответ содержащий "да" ли "нет", с возможностью уточнения "да, логичен", "да, нелогичен" и "нет, нелогичен". Ещё раз прошу прощения за дотошность.

Comment: Артем, Она говорит, что ездила в детский дом. Зачем еще раз спрашивать куда? Где тут логика?

Comment: Допустим их там два, или десять. А ещё магазин детских игрушек "Детский дом".

Comment: Артем, Она вам говорит, что ездила **в детский дом**. Невежливо это игнориривать. Вопрос можно поставить так: "В какой именно детский дом (в Барсуках)?"

Comment: Да, но вопрос уже был задан, и как задать его по-другому, более правильно, меня не интересует. Меня интересует семантика приведенного мною примера.

Comment: И не только невежливо, но и нелогично, так как вы начинаете уточнять с более высокого уровня (Барсуки) в то врема как вы уже  находитесь на уровне "детские дома в Барсуках". (Объясняю как технать технарю)

Comment: "Меня интересует семантика приведенного мною примера" --- Я ответил на вопрос о логичности. А семантика состоит в том, что человек хочет знать, куда именно в Барсуках ездила дама.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87517/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: **Куда именно в Барсуках?**

1. Топоним *Барсуки* склоняется, так как все топонимы русского, славянского происхождения должны склоняться (при употреблении с родовым названием могут быть исключения из этого правила, но это выходит за рамки данного вопроса).
2. В вопросе "Куда именно в Барсуках?" топоним должен стоять в предложном падеже. 
   Можно предположить, что автор вопроса думает, что можно поставить топоним в винительном падеже ("Куда именно в Барсуки?", как "Куда именно в Москву?"). Если говорят "В Москву, а именно в детский дом", то почему бы не спросить "Куда именно в Москву?" Но такой ход мысли неверен. Топоним после слов "куда именно" должен  отвечать на вопрос *где?*, а не *куда?* Корректно: "Куда именно в Москве?", "Куда именно в Барсуках?"

Answer (score 0):

Появилось дополнение к вопросу:

> Корректно использование в вопросе и ответе одной и той же падежной формы топонима.

Давайте разберемся.

Вопрос: "Куда ты ездила?" Ответ: "Я ездила в Барсуки" или "Я ездила в детский дом, в Барсуки".

Примечание: топоним в вопросе не фигурирует.

Вопрос: "Куда именно в Барсуках ты ездила?" Ответ: "В Барсуках я ездила в детский дом".

Примечание: топоним в вопросе и в ответе стоит в одном и том же падеже.

Заметьте: "Я ездила в детский дом, в Барсуки" не является ответом на вопрос "Куда именно в Барсуках ты ездила?".